# Same controller method for different routes

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes

I have this 2 routes:

```
$router->resources([
            'groups'         => Master\GroupController::class,
            'nations/{nation}/groups'           => Master\GroupController::class,
]);
```

In one of them is the list of all the groups and in the other only those that belong to their nation. The problem comes when editing or deleting a record when list all the groups. This is the edit methods:

```php
public function edit($nation = null, $id, Content $content) {
  return $content -> header(__('Group')) 
                  -> description(__('Edit')) 
                  -> body($this -> form() -> edit($id));
}

public function show($nation = null, $id, Content $content)
{
    return $content
        ->header(__('Group'))
        ->description(__('Details'))
        ->body($this->detail($id));
}
```

Error:

```
Too few arguments to function App\Admin\Controllers\GroupController::show(), 2 passed and exactly 3 expected
```

The problem is that the parameter $nation does not exist when I access through the first route, but I do not know how to exclude it.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Please, add more info about your routes. Seems like they use different controller methods, because of your error. Are they post/get/...?

Comment: method is edit or show?

Comment: @Tarasovych added more info in routes. quickSwap, same problem with edit or show method.